# Using reserved word field name in DocumentDB

Tags: sql, field, azure-cosmosdb, reserved

I inherited a database loaded into DocumentDB, where field name happens to be "Value".
Example of my structure is:

```
{
...
   "Alternates": [
      "Type": "ID",
      "Value" : "NOCALL"
   ]
}
```

when I query (using documentDB's SQL), trying to get back all documents where `Alternates.Value = "NOCALL",` I get syntax error near

> "Value" error

. If I query for `Type = "ID",` it is all fine.

Seems that the word Value, having a special meaning on DocumentDB is causing an issue.

Putting punctuation (e.g. quotes/double quotes) around "Value" does not seem to help.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this will be much appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried square brackets? Alternates.[Value] = "NOCALL"

Comment: yes, I have: Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '['.

Comment: Seeing exact same issue for column name `Order`

Answer (score 36):

You are correct. Value is a reserved keyword. 
To escape this use [""] syntax.

So in your case of

"Alternates": [
      "Type": "ID",
      "Value" : "NOCALL"
   ]

SELECT c 
FROM c
JOIN alt IN c.Alternates
WHERE alt["Value"] = 'NOCALL'

Comment: Thanks Ryank for giving this, It saved a lot of time in refactoring the performance of my automation scripts, Can you please share the reference as well from where you learned this trick

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the structure looks something like this - { "name": "ABC", "Value": 123 }.

I could escape the reserved keyword using [""] (as answered by others) along with <source_name> i.e. 
SELECT c["Value"] FROM c -- 123

Ref.: [Querying in Azure Cosmos DB](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/03-querying_in_azure_cosmosdb.html#dot-and-quoted-property-projection-accessors)