# Unable to fetch results when JSON includes sql keywords

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, cosmos

I am trying to fetch records on cosmos db that match a certain condition but I have been unable to, looks like cosmos is complaining about left and I have been unable to find an alternative.

Here is the query that I have been trying to fetch records with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Rx c 
where c.tenantId = '5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007' AND 
      c.left.series ='Clariti 1 Day Toric 30pk'
```

Below is a sample JSON document

```
{
"startDate": null,
"expirationDate": null,
"left": {
    "seriesId": "54b80bae7558391d0044ffd7",
    "productId": null,
    "productName": null,
    "series": "Clariti 1 Day Toric 30pk"
},
"right": null,
"tenantId": "5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007"
}
```

Here is the error being returned:
Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'left'.

Comment: I have tried that, the syntax error goes away but no results are returned.  SELECT * FROM Rx c where c.tenantId = '5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007' AND c.series='Clariti 1 Day Toric 30pk'                                                           
SELECT * FROM Rx c where c.tenantId = '5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007' AND "left.series"='Clariti 1 Day Toric 30pk'

Comment: The JSON field is named as left.series, we are new to Cosmos. If dataexplorer is complaining because left is a keyword, should we consider renaming the field?

Comment: Have you tried using surrounding quotes? This other question is quite similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849310/using-reserved-word-field-name-in-documentdb

Comment: Thank you, I was unable to find it until you sent the link and yes, it is the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: Also, aside from the now-marked-as-duplicate question link shared by @JaimeDrq, I posted an answer to a related question, regarding the use of special characters within a property name, also requiring brackets to resolve properly. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219609/272109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should use **`[]`** instead of **`dot`** when you are querying nested objects

Square bracket notation lets you to access properties containing special characters

```
SELECT * 
FROM Rx c 
where c.tenantId = '5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007' AND 
      c["left"]["series"] ='Clariti 1 Day Toric 30pk'
```

**DEMO**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sajeetharan! no syntax errors and I am getting a result set back.

Comment: Just wondering, if the id was not used what would be a good index to satisfy the Where condition without full scan? Thanks.